# Dapper returns 01-01-0001 00:00:00 from MySQL DATETIME

Tags: mysql, datetime, dapper

I can't get Dapper to work together with MySQL database `DATETIME` type. It always returns `"01-01-0001 00:00:00"` for `DATETIME` columns. Here are some details:

```
.NET: 
DNX 4.5.1
MysqlData 6.9.8
Dapper - 1.50.0-beta6
MySQL: Server Version: 5.5.43-0+deb8u1
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE campaign (
  id int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ...
  creation_date datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  last_modified datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
)
ENGINE = INNODB
```

C#:

```
public class Campaign 
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime CreationDate {get; set; }
     public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
     public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
 }


...
const string myConnectionString = "server=[IP];uid=[usr];pwd=[pass];database=[db];AllowZeroDatetime=false;";
 try
 {
     _conn = new MySqlConnection { ConnectionString = myConnectionString };
     _conn.Open();
 }
...

public Dictionary<int, Campaign> GetCampaigns()
{
            var campaignsDict = _conn.Query<Campaign>("select * from campaign").ToDictionary(row => row.Id,row => row);
            return campaignsDict;
}
```

that's how one retrieved row looks inside the campaignsDict:

[image]

P.S. I'm just learning .NET, so I'm a noob in this technology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper  does not automatically remove underscores unless told to do so, via:

```
Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
```

So what you actually have here is properties that *haven't been mapped from columns*. The default value of a `DateTime` is: 01-01-0001 00:00:00.

Options:

- enable underscore matching
- alias the columns in the query to match the properties
- change the properties to match the database columns
- write a custom type map

Answer (score 0):

Change your model so that date columns are optional like this:

```
public class Campaign 

{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public DateTime? CreationDate {get; set; }
     public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
     public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
     public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
 }
```